# Xpath evaluation in javascript not working relative to some element

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, selenium

The code below will reach the "before" and "between" alerts, but not the "after" alert.

```
alert("before")

var test = document.evaluate('.//*',document,document.createNSResolver(document),XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null)
alert(element.tagName)//alerts "TABLE" 
alert("between")
test = document.evaluate('.//*',element,document.createNSResolver(document),XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null)
alert("after")
```

This is written as part of a selenium extension. and `alert(document)` in the code gives a different result than `alert(document)` when run in firebug. [object XULDocument] vs [object HTMLDocument].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

`document` does not refer to the HTML document in selenium extensions. however each element has a reference to the document which owns it. in this case

```
test = document.evaluate('.//*',element,document.createNSResolver(document),
XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null)
```

becomes

```
test = element.ownerDocument.evaluate('.//*',element,
element.ownerDocument.createNSResolver(element.ownerDocument),
XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null)
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Your second test has an undefined variable `element`.

Comment: it's not undefined, it's just not defined in what I posted. just assume it's some element in the document.

Comment: hm... while looking at this page and typing into console `var element = document.getElementById('footer'); test = document.evaluate('.//*',element,document.createNSResolver(document),XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);` returns a usable `XPathResult` object.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Zackkenyon answer, without the resolver seems to work.

```
var rangee = table.ownerDocument.evaluate("./tbody/tr", table, null,
XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

Comment: This is an answer. You don't need to apologize for it.